# Is there any way for me to run a nodejs application as a server and it communicate with deployed electron applications?

Tags: node.js, electron

I recently created a client side application using electron which currently runs standalone. I would like it to have functionality where I can send a string to all of the electron applications, possibly by creating a nodejs server to do this. The electron applications would then receive this string  and use it within whatever function I attach to it.

This is not the electron frontend communicating with the backend. This is an external nodejs server communicating with the electron backend. So it would be 1 main nodejs application running as a server and electron applications deployed on different machines.

Is this actually possible to achieve?

Are there any node packages which could allow this communication from the main server to the electron applications? Any documented packages would be of great help so I can understand how it functions before integrating it.

I saw socket-io but that seemed more web based client-server, unless I am interpreting it wrong?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Electron is just Chromium and Node in one runtime. So you can call any server from your electron app as you would do it in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Hope I understand your question correctly.

Each Electron installation could run a web server in their main or renderer process.

The Electron installations would need to communicate their current IP address to the "main" node server to facilitate callbacks to them from the "root" server node.

The main server node would then call back to each current Electron instance and inform them of the latest string value.

You will run into networking proxy / firewall / security related issues if doing this over the open internet. You need to be sure about what/why you would want to do this. It would only work in some limited scenarios.

A more practical alternative to doing this would be to routinely "poll" the main server from each Electron instance and get the latest string value.

You can consider alternatives such as web sockets, message queues, reactive technologies, a "notification" API on some mobile/desktop platforms, or a peer-to-peer protocol?

Such solutions might be easier or more appropriate depending on your application. E.g. are you implementing a "chat" application, are you streaming audio and video, etc?

Interesting question!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's too easy, I am sharing you about my experience. 
Just create your server.js file of the node.js and with proper path call that file in the index.js of electron generated file.

```
//server.js

const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(cors());

app.listen(8880, function () {
    console.log("Listen to Port 8880!");
});
```

the call your node server file in index js

```
//index.js

const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = require('electron');

const express = require('./server.js'); <--- calling your node js
```

now just need to execute electron command and. yeehh!! its working and your node server are also live on PORT whatever you have given.
through this way you can create your REST API in node and take benefits of it in ELECTRONJS.
Hope you got your answer.